# Sorting Matrix's Header Sequence

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am facing an issues while trying to sort my matrix header sequence

What I am trying to achieve is to display my matrix header sequence starting from Current, 1 period, 2 period, 3 period, 4 period, and then Total. I have tried creating a new table and setting up the desired sequence, but I am encountering a circular dependency error when I try to sort by column.
[image]

Greatly appreciate any guidance or help that you can provide to solve this issue. If it is possible, please find my pbix file attached for your reference.

Pbix : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jOZrjlTcDxJL3AQ15kBX8y4IYOGpoYIg/view?usp=share_link

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

In your matrix header **column** simply replace

```
"Current Mar 2023"
```

with

```
" Current Mar 2023"
```

When sorting, " " comes prior to "1"